# How to proccess token?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have a question.
In my project, after a user loges in my app generates an access token and then put it on cookies.
This access token contains information like user rights and some other details about him.

For authentication part I use 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' which is mapped to a class that subclasses TokenAuthentication class from rest_framework.authentication.

Instead of decoding again the access token in every view, how can I have it's rights from access token?
What should I use?
May put decoded token in request.session?

Answer (score 1):

Store the access token in a cookie (or session) and for every relevant request to the server, add the following header:

`Authorization: Token [your_token_from_the_cookie]`

On the view you want to protect with a token authentication, add the appropriate decorators:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', etc.])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication,])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
```

Some of these decorators can be set globally in your settings file.

In short, ask for the token once, store it, and then use it everytime you make a request that should require authentication.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/